# Jupyter Notebook SOCKS connection fails while running a SOCKS proxy. Ideas?

Tags: proxy, jupyter-notebook, socks

So I am having an issue where starting up a **local** Jupyter Notebook fails due to socks proxy connection error:

```
The webpage at http://localhost:8888/tree?token=xxxx...xxxx might be
temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

I'm running a socks proxy over ssh tunnel at the same time that I am working on Jupyter. They already run on different ports. Is there a workaround that doesn't involve me reimplementing my proxy in a different protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out...

Set proxy to bypass localhost did the trick.